# Connection was not closed, Connection's current state is open error in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a web app using a databound checkboxlist. I have an update stored procedure that I placed in a foreach loop. If one CheckboxList is checked, the update is fine, but if I have more than one checked it throws the connection is open error. I tried a `try{}catch{}finally{}` but it's still giving me the same error

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddy", provider, style, out dt);
int i = Int32.Parse(amount.Text);

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;


 foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
 {
     if(item.Selected)
     {

          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[AccountCode_Update]";
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Batch_Num", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Batch_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BatchCodeList.SelectedValue;
          conn.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }


  }
  conn.Close();
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE AccountTable
(
  RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
  AccountID varchar(2),
  AccountName varchar(50),
  SeqNum int,
  SeqDate datetime
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [AccountCode_Update]
(
  @Batch_Num int,
  @Batch_Date datetime,
  @Account_Code varchar(2)
)

 AS 
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 BEGIN
  UPDATE AccountTable
   SET SeqNum = @Batch_Num, SeqDate = @Batch_Date
   WHERE AccountID = @Account_Account_Code
 END
```

Comment: The error's pretty descriptive. You can't open an open connection. You are opening your connection inside the loop, but not closing it inside the loop. Move the open to immediately after the declaration/initialization and you should be good. Further, wrap up your SqlCommand and SqlConnection in using blocks instead of using a discrete Close call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your `conn.Open();` call before your `foreach` loop.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;

conn.Open();

foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
    if(item.Selected)
    {

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[AccountCode_Update]";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Batch_Num", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Batch_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BatchCodeList.SelectedValue;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

conn.Close();
```

What's happening is that you are calling `conn.Open()` of a connection that is already open and it throws an error. This is why the first call works and the next ones fail.

Take a look at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `Open()` method. It has some examples of what will cause exceptions.

In this case

> **InvalidOperationException**
>
> Cannot open a connection without specifying a data source or server.
>   or
>   **The connection is already open.**

Comment: would clearing the parameters be efficient also? I tested that and now getting a too many argument specified error. Which could be because of the loop?

Comment: I added your suggestion as well as what @Javad_Amiry about clearing the parameters and I don't get either errors anymore. thank you

Comment: This is mostly a simplified description of what is going on. You can do this a number of ways for improvements such as opening and closing the connection for each call and such. If you're doing a large number of calls to the database and is high traffic, you'll want to take more precautions such as what @Javad_Amiry suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Close the connection! Also, you'll need to clear command-parameters in each loop.

```
 foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
 {
     if(item.Selected)
     {

          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[AccountCode_Update]";
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Batch_Num", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Batch_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BatchCodeList.SelectedValue;
          conn.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          conn.Close();
          cmd.Parameters.Clear(); // you need to clear previous parameters
     }


  }
```

**UPDATE:** OK. I saw @Krik's answer, and I need to describe:

One of the basic rules in working with ADO.NET is this: **Open a connection AS LATE AS POSSIBLE, and, Close it AS SOON AS POSSIBLE.** So, you shouldn't keep opened a connection through a loop, since you are doing some not-database-related operations here. Such as clearing command's parameters and refilling it. So, this would be ideal:

```
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

conn.Open should be outside foreach.

Once it is opened. it is trying to open again on second item.Selected.